# In Rails, how do I test that a particular model method is called by a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller, say `FoosController`, wrapping a model `Foo`. `Foo` has_many `Bar`.

I can do `@foo.bars` inside my contrller, but if I know that `Bar` in turn has other relationships, I want to be efficient and pre-fetch items. To simplify it, I have defined on my model `Foo` the method:

```
def bars_deep
  bars.includes([:other,:stuff])
end
```

I want to test that when I call certain methods of my controller, that it calls `@foo.bars_deep` and not just `@foo.bars`.

How do I do that? I tried using `MiniTest::Mock`, but it failed:

```
f = @foo
mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
mock.expect :call, nil, []
f.stub :bars_deep, mock do
  get :cmethod, id: @foo
end
assert mock.verify
```

The problem is that it is mocking on *this* instance of `Foo`, but a different one is loaded inside the controller.

How can I test that my controller is calling `bars_deep` and thus properly preparing and not just `bars`?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23313791/3109182) is what you're after.

Comment: @Anthony not sure it works. That case has tests on a model from that model. My problem here is that a new model instance is called from within the controller, so it doesn't have the stub!