# Testing callbacks with minitest rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a before_validation callback in my model. I am unable to find how to write test cases for callbacks in minitest rails.

```
test 'callback set_slug before_validation' do
  company = Company.new(name: 'test')
  mock_method = MiniTest::Mock.new
  mock_method.expect :set_slug, 'clickapps1'
  company.stub :set_slug, 'clickapps1' do
    company.valid?
  end
  mock_method.verify
end
```

Comment: If you googled, you could find this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293021/check-method-call-on-model-using-minitest

Comment: I have already tried this and the solutions given on the link you mentioned are not working.

Comment: If you could provide code samples of what you tried and what is not working we could better provide some pointers.

Comment: I have a before validation callback in my company model:  

before_validation :set_slug, unless: :slug  

The test case I have written is:  
`test 'callback set_slug before_validation' do  
    company = Company.new(name: 'test')  
    mock_method = MiniTest::Mock.new  
    mock_method.expect :set_slug, 'clickapps1'  
    company.stub :set_slug, 'clickapps1' do  
      company.valid?  
    end  
    mock_method.verify  
  end`

Answer (score 6):

I used the mocha gem and then my test case looks like:

```
test 'callback set_slug before_validation' do
  company = Company.new(name: 'test')
  company.expects(:set_slug)
  company.valid?
 end
```

and now it works.

Comment: holy cow! the internet is full with crapy mocking solutions. THIS ACTUALLY IS THE REAL SCENARIO! it works like a charme!

Comment: Yes, don't stuff around trying to do it another way. This is by far the easiest and quickest.